# how to change the order of aggreation filter in magento 2 in di.xml

Tags: magento2.3, graphql, di.xml

*Magento/Cataloggraphql/etc/graphql/di.xml*

```
 <type name="Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="builders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="price_bucket" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\Builder\Price</item>
                <item name="category_bucket" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\Builder\Category</item>
                <item name="attribute_bucket" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\Builder\Attribute</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

here based on this

filter layer (aggregations) in magento 2

showing

> price
>
> category
>
> custom_attributes

here

i want to change the order of this

**expected result**
(order only changed)

> category
>
> price
>
> custom_attributes

i tried to copy to my custom module but

don't change in order

*when i change order in core file 
it working as expected.*

**how i can achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer

*MyModule/etc/graphql/di.xml*

```
 <type name="Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\LayeredNavigation\LayerBuilder">
        <plugin name="category_aggregation_order_change" type="Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\LayerBuilder" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

using

**after plugin**

to solved this problem.